# Can not tweak collider`s border manually in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, ide

Why can not I change collider`s border manually? I remember being able to do that. I just clicked the gray button under in this case Box Collider 2D component, then went to the Scene view and tweaked it as I wanted by clicking and moving collider`s border. But now when I do the same procedure on trying to click and drag the border in Scene view I am just losing focus of the collider, but do not change it in any way.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset layout to `Default` and then back to your work layout (if needed) and collider editing will work.

Also, you can close the `Inspector` and `Hierarchy` tab and then - reopen it.

Taken from `Unity` forums:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/969724/i-cant-edit-my-collider-cursor-even-if-i-pressed-t.html

Comment: Closing `Inspector`, `Hierarchy` and then reopening them does not work. But the first approach worked out. I see no reasons for the Layout and my tweaking of collider borders to be connected. It is just a bug in the Editor. Am I right?

Comment: It's probably a bug. It may happen when you have two inspectors opened :) Usually, restarting Unity fixes visual bugs like this one.

Comment: in the case restarting Editor does nothing.

Comment: It must be connected somehow to the `Inspector`'s layout. Probably it clears the cache (restarting doesn't) :)